# MongoDB how to assign properties of subdocument to parent in aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've got an aggregation that, right now, returns objects looking like:

```
"_id": ObjectId("58f15197315e16762fbd2f0d"),
"versionCount": 3,
"article": {
  "_id": ObjectId("58f152ecd549c4783a84f844"),
  "otherProps": "etc..."
}
```

I've gone through quite a few aggregation steps to get here. There are quite a few properties under `article`. Problem is, I want it to return articles with the `versionCount` property. I could do a `$project` and individually assign each property to the parent document, but that would take many lines of code and be relatively fragile. Is there a more efficient way to take all of the properties from `article` and assign them to the documents returned by the aggregation?

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: Mongo version 3.2.12

Comment: I'm afraid you have to map them manually for that version.

Comment: For my info and others who might find the post, could you answer for Mongo 3.4? I'll be able to upgrade shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$addFields` to add the top level fields to the sub document and use `$replaceRoot` to promote sub document to top level.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "article.doc_id":"$_id",
        "article.versionCount": "$versionCount"
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$article"
    }
})
```

Comment: This certainly works. Out of curiosity, is this the best practice of promoting fields?